# reading android style xml

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I have a custom style that I would like to apply to my views.
I was not able to create my views programatically, not through XML, as it is a dynamic content amount (same view can appear X times, but no more then 10, so I do not want a list).

if i can get an XmlPullParser of the style, I can easly use `AttributeSet attrs = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);`
 and pass it to the View's C'tor.  The problem is obtaining the XmlPullParser.
getresources().getX does not have a getStyle() method. Maybe I'm just taking the wrong approach.
Does anybody have any idea how to apply the style to a programatic view?

10x.

ok, i tried the third C'tpr parameter approach:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this, null, R.style.my_style_2);
    tv.setText("this should be green!");
    setContentView(tv);
}
```

and the style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="my_style_2">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FF00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I don't get big green text. I get default size gray text...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Other way would be just create the View programmatically and use the style parameter within the constructor:

E.g: TextView myTextView = new TextView(context, null, R.style.myCustomStyle);

Comment: and that works / i was sure the second parameter is for the attributes from the style and the last one is for the theme, not style, but i'll give it a shot anyway :-) it just could be the deal :-)

Comment: The 2nd attribute (AttributeSet) holds the attributes from xml layout definition. The 3rd parameter references the style. The loading order is: 1) load from theme (which is defined globally for the app. 2) overwrite data from styles and 3) overwrite with data from xml layout

Comment: nop :-( doesn't do th trick... i put my style in the last parameter and it's ignored, according to your priority of things it should have worked.i added my testing code to my question above.

Comment: yeah sry. I haven't tested the code of my answer - I only took a look into the implementation of the constructor of the View class and thought, it should work.

Comment: seems like this way is not possible. Reading a bit more into the C'tor docs it seems that you need to specify not the style but an R.attr.X which is attribute that points to the right style or styles in the current theme, i used it when i customized Views using my own theme and that's it's purpose, but putting a regualr style xml will not solve the issue.
possible workaround may be defining this attribute to point to my style and define it in the theme, then make the activity point to this theme, i'll post code later on.

Answer (score 1):

I hope, this answer can help: I would define the view, which can appear x times, in a separate layout file and use the layout inflater to add them dynamically / programmatically.

Sample code:

```
LayoutInflater l = getLayoutInflater(); // is a method from activity class
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    l.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_view_entry,  parentView);
}
```

custom_list_view_entry.xml in the res/layout folder define your list entry layout and contain all style information or a more complex view hierarchy. 
parentView is the view, which is the container for the list entries.

Comment: i have several of those, i had it with defining them this way, it makes our layout directory big and untidy.
this is why i'm asking specifically about applying a style.